# require all templates including files with underscores

Tags: brunch

With brunch, I can require all files in a folder like this

```
require('/templates/');
```

But that does not cover files with underscores, I still need to require them like this:

```
require('templates/_mood');
```

How could I require all files in the templates folder including files with underscores?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr you can’t simply.

`require('/templates/');` does not load all files, instead it loads `templates/index` file by default. in `index` you can require all files in current directory and that way your problem will be solved